# VPN security/compromise

Tags: authentication, certificates

I want to get a VPN with one of the known providers. I don't know much about VPNs but I know they issue certificates which you download and it authenticates the connection and basically gives access. I have some questions though.

1. When you download the VPN certificates, even though they're being downloaded through HTTPS are they actually safe from eavesdroppers and your ISP? Let's say the encrypted HTTPS was stored and then decrypted and those certificates were uncovered, wouldn't pretty much give them total access to the VPN connection?
2. Are iVPN and Mullvad good VPNs for privacy?
3. If you use the VPN provider's client do you still need to download "network-manager-openvpn" from the repository?
4. The VPN client from the provider(s) is open source and shouldn't be backdoored but could still have exploits so the question is does it mean a new attack vector against the host?

I don't think I've fully realized how VPNs work so forgive me. If somebody could explain to me how I have understood it wrong it would be appreciated.

EDIT: What I ment in the first question was regarding the initial download of the configuration certificates and if it would be possible for a malicious third party to gain access to them during download or even decrypt the HTTPS sometime after download of the certificates and therefore have the keys to the connection.

Comment: What are you looking to get our of the VPN service?  The term VPN has been morphed over the last few years.

Answer (score 1):

I'll do my best to answer your points, as each situation is different.

1 - If you're using an SSL VPN solution (which is probably the case), the only way they would be able to decrypt your traffic is if they got a hold of the VPN servers private key (this is the way SSL/TLS works). Even if your traffic is captured, they wouldn't be able to decrypt it without the private key, unless a very weak cipher is being used (i'm leaving out the possibility of a MITM attack).

2 - I personally use iVPN on a daily basis with a PPTP VPN setup. I like it, very good for the price you pay and extremely easy to setup. I have no experience with Mullvad.

3 - This isn't very clear - every provider is different. You might not even need a 3rd party client depending on the solution you go for. I use my Mac VPN settings to connect to my iVPN server from my MacBook, and the iPhone VPN settings from my phone. Both support VPN connections out of the box. Windows does too.

4 - It's always good to be weary about open source solutions, but generally, if you download a client from a reputable provider and you're paying for the service, they are responsible for making sure their software does not contain malicious code - even if they are building their solution from Open source software. Exploits can still be (and will be) discovered, not much that can be done to prevent that - but they should provide patches to fix any exploits which are discovered.

There is a lot of every good documentation on how VPNs work, and their purpose. There's a lot of information here:

http://computer.howstuffworks.com/vpn.htm

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wouldn't use a PPTP VPN: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PPTP#Security

Comment: I'd be much more willing to trust an open source client, with many thousands of people looking at the code and improving it than a closed source client where god know who has done god knows what to the code.

Comment: You're absolutely right - iVPN supports L2TP too, but my home router doesn't support passthrough.  I don't really deal with very sensitive data.